# how to order a queryset in Django model by relational foreign key

Tags: django, rest, model, foreign-keys

I have the following models

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
      label = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
      description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

class Expense(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        related_name='category'
)
```

```
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Category.objects.order_by("-expense__expense")
```

I'm struggling to how to return a Category list ordered by the most picked category in the Expense model like:

```
<Expense category=3>
<Expense category=3>
<Expense category=2>
<Expense category=3>
<Expense category=1>
<Expense category=1>
```

I want to return in this order:

```
<Category id=3>
<Category id=1>
<Category id=2>
```

## Solution is using annotate:

```
queryset = Category.objects.annotate(
        expense_count=Count('category')).order_by('-expense_count')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from django.db.models import Count

Category.objects.annotate(expense_count=Count('category')).order_by('-expense_count')
```

This is based on your model definition yet I suggest that the `related_name` should be modified to a term that related to `Expense`, such as `expenses`. Since the `related_name` indicate the name you are using for reverse querying.

Answer (score 0):

Use Django's lovely [aggregation features](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/).

```
queryset = Category.objects.annotate(expense_count=Count('expense')).order_by('-expense_count')
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) to achieve this:

```
from django.db.models import Count

...

queryset = Category.objects.annotate(expense_count=Count('expense')).order_by('-expense_count')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add .distinct('field-name') at end of the query. like this

```
queryset = Category.objects.order_by("-expense__expense").distinct('category')
```